# Finding the total mass of a rod without integration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass

Consider a rod with mass density $\rho(x)$. Then, we can calculate the mass of the rod for a given interval by integrating mass density in the given interval such as:$$\int^{m_b}_{m_a}\text dm=\int_a^b \rho\, \text dx\Rightarrow$$ $$M=m_b-m_a$$ So knowing the mass in the two endpoints mean we can calculate the mass in the given interval? What I am getting wrong?

Comment: I dont know what you mean with $M=m_b-m_a$. If by $m_b$ or $m_a$ you meant the start and end masses, then the formula does not have any sense and it is wrong.

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean. This is the same with do with displacement: $$\int_{x_a}^{x_b}dx= \int_{t_a}^{t_b}udt \Rightarrow$$ $$\Delta x=x_b-x_a=\int_{t_a}^{t_b}udt$$

Comment: This is just a problem of how to understand definite integration. The correct interpretation is $M=m_b-m_a$, where $m_b$ is the mass from $-\inf$ to point $b$, and $m_a$ is the mass from $-\inf$ to point $a$. So without surprise, $m_b-m_a$ is the mass between point $a$ and point $b$.

Comment: Endpoints have no volume and thus no mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking of using the integral $M=\int\text dm$, then you could understand this as an accumulation. i.e. we are starting with no mass in our sum, and ending with all of the mass. Therefore, in your expression we could have $m_a=0$ and $m_b=M$. Then we have the correct expression
$$\int_0^M\text dm=M$$

If the above is somewhat unsettling, I agree. I think the issue is that we want to try to stick with specifying limits on our integral, but really this is not always the case. For example, for surface or volume integrals, we specify a region of integration. For your mass integral, really we should just have 
$$M=\int_\text{all mass}\text dm$$

i.e., add up $\text dm$ over the entire object. Integrals are, after all, just sums.

In any case, the integral $\int\text dm$ is not an integral with any spatial information encoded into it, so trying to say that $m_a$ and $m_b$ (whatever they are) are the "mass of the endpoints" doesn't make sense. Really, the second integral I have listed makes the most sense, and it can easily be turned into an integral we can handle given the density $\rho(x)$
$$M=\int_\text{all mass}\text dm=\int_\text{entire length}\rho(x)\,\text dx$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I get it wrong in the interpretation of the integral. We do the same thing in calculating the displacement. $$\int_{x_a}^{x_b}dx= \int_{t_a}^{t_b}udt \Rightarrow$$  $$\Delta x=x_b-x_a=\int_{t_a}^{t_b}udt$$

Comment: @adosar There is no such thing as $m_a$ and $m_b$. What would these even mean? An endpoint does not have any mass. So the limits on your integral are nonsense.

Comment: @G.Smith Right. I agree it doesn't make sense. I am trying to think of a better way to explain everything.

Comment: This not a way to find the mass. You, in fact, already know it, then just insert it into your integration!

Comment: @Gert I don't really understand your objection. The OP is not asking how to find the mass, but rather how to interpret the integral $\int\text dm$ And why would we insert $M$ into an integral?

Comment: @AaronStevens I read your edited answer and I think this is where I got it wrong. The spatial information is missing in the left integral whereas in integral time to get the displacement the spatial information is there. Thank you so much.